# Swift, preventing tableview cell resueable

Tags: swift, tableview, reusability, uitableview

How to solve the table view data overlapped issue?
I have searched some Object C version answer, but it seems not working for Swift. I tried to get cell==nil, but it gives me an error

```
      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let current_patient = patients[indexPath.row]
    let cell = myTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PatientTableViewCell
    if (cell){
        let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("patientCell") as! PatientTableViewCell
    }
    let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("patientCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PatientTableViewCell
    if(cell != nil){
        var subviews = cell.contentView.subviews
        subviews.removeAll()
    }
   //configure cell
   let type = current_patient.enrollable_type
   cell.patientTypelbl.text = type
   return cell
   }
```

After two-days struggling, I figure it out finally. The key to solve it is to find which cell is been resued. What I am doing now is give a var identifier to cell.

```
    class PatientTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var followupBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var viewBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var titleType: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleID: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var patientTypelbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var patientIDlbl: UILabel!

**var identifier = false**
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let current_patient = patients[indexPath.row]

    var cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("patientCell") as! PatientTableViewCell
           if(cell.identifier == true){
        cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("patientCell") as! PatientTableViewCell
    }
    //config cell
    cell.identifier = true   //important
```

I hope it can help someone else. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let current_patient = patients[indexPath.row]
    let cell: PatientTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("patientCell") as? PatientTableViewCell

    //configure cell
    let type = current_patient.enrollable_type
    cell.patientTypelbl.text = type
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the data still overlapped.